# What is the big O for the complexity O(sqrt(n) * log(sqrt(n))) + O(n)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

What will be the Big O notation for the above complexity?

Is it O(n)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.  The key is that the square root inside the log makes no difference:

```
O(sqrt(n) log(sqrt(n))) = O(sqrt(n) 1/2 log(n)) = O(sqrt(n) log(n)).
```

With this in hand, we notice

```
O(n) = O(sqrt(n)sqrt(n)) > O(sqrt(n)log(n)).
```

This is because in any case

```
O(sqrt(n)) > O(log(n)).
```

Why?  We can take the log on both sides to verify, and again a square root appears inside a log:

```
O(log(sqrt(n)) = O(1/2 log(n)) = O(log(n)) > O(log log(n))
```

So we can finally conclude the overall result is O(n).

Answer (score 3):

O(n) drowns out O(sqrt(n)) and O(log(sqrt(n))

Answer (score 0):

O(sqrt(n) * **log(sqrt(n))**) + O(n) <= O(sqrt(n) * **sqrt(n)**) + O(n)

O(**sqrt(n) * sqrt(n)**) + O(n) = O(**n**) + O(n)

O(n) + O(n) = O(n)